# Removing url params using regex

Tags: regex, url, parameters

I have problem with removing params from url starting on ":". I have example path like:

```
/foo/:some_id/bar/:id
```

I would like to archive following result:

```
/foo/bar
```

I tried to create some regex. I figured out this:

```
\/:.*?\/
```

But this one removes :some_id but still It leaves :id part. Can you tell me how I can modify my regex to remove all params?

Comment: split by `/`. iterate through items. if it doesnt start with `:`, append it.

Comment: This should help you: https://regex101.com/r/tG0oG0/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex requires a `/` to be present at the end. You cannot just remove the `/` from the regex since `.*?` won't match anything then. Use a [**negated character class**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated):

```
\/:[^\/]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uT0eK2/1)

**Pattern details**:

- `\/:` - matches a literal `/:`
- `[^\/]+` - matches 1+ characters other than `/` as `[^...]` defines a negated character class matching all characters but those defined in the class.

Comment: Thanks for solution and explanation ;)